# Is there a better method for find and replace in Vim?

Tags: vim

Edit: I moved this over to the Vi and Vim site:  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13689/how-to-find-and-replace-in-vim-without-having-to-type-the-original-word

I'd like to optimize my "find and replace" workflow in Vim. It's something I do often, as I'm sure most of you do too. Usually something along the lines of -- *copy a block and change the name of a variable in a few places.* I know, I know, that probably triggers your "why are you copying and pasting code" reflex, but let's not go down that road... There are plenty of valid use cases :)

I'm well aware of the search and replace commands: `:s` or `:%s` but I don't like them. It forces me to type out both the full variable name I'm searching for and what I'm changing it to. Maybe there is a better way fix the the amount of typing with `:%s`? I often use long descriptive variable names, so that is really a deal breaker for me. I also don't like how typing out a variable name from scratch is typo prone and can consume time and brainpower hunting down typos. I much prefer typing it once, and then copying and pasting to just avoid this entirely if possible.

My current workflow uses some combination of movement/yank/select/search/put to move around the file and replace one by one. It is not great but has the benefit of avoiding typing out full variable names. I might just need to type the first few letters with `/` or use another movement command (i.e. `fx`) depending on what's around and then hit `ve` to select the whole word. I also don't mind that I have to repeat for every instance. I never do a full find replace without confirming each change. But it would be much preferable if I could repeat the replacement action with a single keystroke (which I can't do with this method). each replacement is usually something like `n` then `ve` then `p` (or even worse `"0p`)

Is there a faster way?

Comment: There are many things you can improve in your workflow, see f.i. `:h g&`, `:h :s_c`, `:h objects`, Kana's [textobj-user plugin](https://github.com/kana/vim-textobj-user), and Drew Neil's [vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/).  Also, asking on [vi.se] might trigger fewer rejection mechanisms as here.

Comment: Great point, I totally forgot there was a dedicated community for Vi/Vim.  https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/13689/is-there-a-better-method-for-find-and-replace-in-vim

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it makes more sense on Vi/Vim. I reposted over there.

Answer (score 1):

My own workflow is similar to yours:

- To start, get the cursor on one instance, possibly with `/` or by navigation.
- Hit `*` to find the next instance of that word.
- Change one instance with `cw` and then the new variable name.
- Then it's fast: `n`/`N` to get to the next/previous instance, and `.` to repeat the last edit.

This workflow gives me the same advantage as yours, in that I can review each case before applying the change, but it's just two keystrokes for each additional change.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You can use `gn` motion to work on a search pattern. `cgnfoo<esc>` and then repeat with `. command`. For more see `:h gn`

Answer (score 0):

I like the "visual highlight then edit" approach.

- `shift + v` to highlight the region that you want to modify.
- then `:s/old/new/r` where `old` is what word you want to replace with `new`.
- `r` changes the first instance of that word `old`.

Note* There are options other than `r` which modify its behavior how you want to replace the word.